# Redirect Url To Another Action Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, notifications, redirect

I am doing Notification module. Below code shows the Notification Table model

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public int NotificationID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

when the user click the notification, the `bool Active` should be set to false and then redirected to the url which is sepecified in the Url column. I have finished notifcation through signalR but on clicking notification redirecting to url is not done. I cannot redirect to the specified url.

Comment: Show us your jqyery code.

Comment: On clicking the Notification, the request will be send to a controller along with the notification id where all are processed and then redirected to the specified url. It is not processed in jquery.

Comment: ok, show us the code what you have, unless we see your code we cannot think of solving your problem.

Comment: public ActionResult NotificationRedirect(int NotificationID)
        {
            var notification = db.Notifications.Find(NotificationID);
            ....
            return Redirect(notification.Url);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can update the your table record inside the action method which will be executed when user clicks on a notification item.

```
public ActionResult NotificationRedirect(int notificationId) 
{ 
   var notification = db.Notifications.FirstOrDefault(notificationId);
   if(notification!=null)
   {
       notification.Active=false;
       db.Entry(notification).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();
       return Redirect(notification.Url); 
   } 
   return View("NotificationNotFound"); //make sure you have a view with this name
}
```

Now from your client side, you need to build markup(*when you get a call from singlaR*) with anchor tag where your `href` value is set to the `NotificationRedirect` action method with `notificationId` querystring. Something like

```
<a href="YourControllerName/NotificationRedirect?notificationId=123">Notification tex</a>
```

Also, for redirecting, If you are showing a page which is inside you app, you might consider using `RedirectToAction` method as well.

Comment: Thanks. But     return Redirect(notification.Url);  is not working properly. Then add "../" in front of notification.url     return Redirect("../"+ notification.Url); Now it works correctly

Comment: `Redirect` method expects an abosolute url ( Ex:`http://www.google.com`). Why are you appending `"../"` before the url ? If you are trying to redirect to a page/view in your app, you should consider using `RedirectToAction` method.